# Problem involving matrix spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$  $\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. If $-2\in \sigma(A^2+2*A)$ then $-4\in\sigma(A^{4})$

(where $\sigma$ represents the spectrum of the matrix involved)

I haven't made any useful conclusions whatsoever, I don't even have an idea on how to approach the problem so any kind of hint would be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\det(A^4+4I)=\det\left((A^2+2I-2A)(A^2+2I+2A)\right)=0$ since $-2 \in \sigma(A^2+2A)$. Thus $-4\in\sigma(A^4)$